# 3 for-loops to print the following pattern:

Tags: java, for-loop

My niece asked me this question to her homework at school and i have no idea how to do it.

The teacher asked them to **print this following pattern using 3 for-loops in java**:

```
1******
12*****
123****
1234***
12345**
123456*
1234567
```

kindly help.

thanks!

Comment: So far, what you have done?

Comment: nothing yet since i have no clue on how to print that pattern using 3 for loops

Comment: You only need 2 `for` loops, which makes it pretty hard (for me) to apply 3... Just try something, post it here and I am sure you're gonna get some help, but it is mandatory to show some effort on this site, sorry.

Comment: @deHaar Minor quibble. Off by one error. You only **need** 1 `for` loop.

Comment: @deHaar this is what i got earlier jdoodle.com/a/1BCr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It used to be my homework

Code

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

will show

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
```

and

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    for (int k = 7 - i; k >= 1; k--) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

will show

```
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Final

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    for (int k = 7 - i; k >= 1; k--) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

will show

```
1******
12*****
123****
1234***
12345**
123456*
1234567
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printPattern(int n) {
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for(int k=1; k<=i+1; k++) {
                System.out.print(k);
            }
            for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Are you sure question has been asked to solve by using 3 for loops?
    As it is better to use less loop as much as we can. Secondly there is no requirement in problem to use third loop. you can find the desired result by using two loops:

    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
               for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
                    if (j <= i) {
                            System.out.print(j);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
            }
                System.out.println("\n");
        }
        }
    } 

output will be:
1******
12*****
123****
1234***
12345**
123456*
1234567
```